# Is there a way to call `overridePendingTransition` from a class that does not extend the Activity class?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, transition, android-context

I'm using another class to run some stuff in the background while the main activity is being displayed, and passing that activity's context to this background class. I'm starting another activity from this background class, but am unable to call `overridePendingTransition` here because "method overridePendingTransition(int, int) is undefined for the type BackgroundClass."

```
public class GetUPC extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> 
{       
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        ...
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) 
    {
        ...


                    boolean dairy;
                    if(theDairy.equals("N"))
                    {
                        //milk test
                        dairy=true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dairy=false;
                    }



                    //depending on if there is a warning it will either display the warning screen or skip it
                    if(dairy)
                    {
                        Intent intent_warn = new Intent(context, WarningScreen.class);

                        intent_warn.putExtra("Name", str_name);
                        intent_warn.putExtra("Size", str_size);
                        intent_warn.putExtra("Price", str_price);
                        intent_warn.putExtra("Carbs", str_carbs);
                        intent_warn.putExtra("Protein", str_protein);
                        intent_warn.putExtra("Fiber", str_fiber);
                        intent_warn.putExtra("Sugar", str_sugar);
                        intent_warn.putExtra("SatFat", str_satFat);
                        intent_warn.putExtra("TotFat", str_totFat);
                        intent_warn.putExtra("Cholesterol", str_cholesterol);
                        intent_warn.putExtra("Sodium", str_sodium);
                        intent_warn.putExtra("Potassium", str_potassium);
                        intent_warn.putExtra("Calories", str_calories);
                        intent_warn.putExtra("Warning", "Contains Dairy");
                        intent_warn.putExtra("WarningRed", true);
                        Log.e("Warning",intent_warn.getExtras().getString("Warning"));

                        context.startActivity(intent_warn);
                        overridePendingTransition(R.layout.fade_in, R.layout.fade_out);  //THIS PART ISN'T WORKING//
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Intent intent_menu = new Intent(context, DisplayScreen.class);
                        intent_menu.putExtra("Name", str_name);
                        intent_menu.putExtra("Size", str_size);
                        intent_menu.putExtra("Price", str_price);
                        intent_menu.putExtra("Carbs", str_carbs);
                        intent_menu.putExtra("Protein", str_protein);
                        intent_menu.putExtra("Fiber", str_fiber);
                        intent_menu.putExtra("Sugar", str_sugar);
                        intent_menu.putExtra("SatFat", str_satFat);
                        intent_menu.putExtra("TotFat", str_totFat);
                        intent_menu.putExtra("Cholesterol", str_cholesterol);
                        intent_menu.putExtra("Sodium", str_sodium);
                        intent_menu.putExtra("Potassium", str_potassium);
                        intent_menu.putExtra("Calories", str_calories);
                        intent_menu.putExtra("Warning",  "Contains no allergens");
                        intent_menu.putExtra("WarningRed", false);
                        Log.e("Warning",intent_menu.getExtras().getString("Warning"));

                        context.startActivity(intent_menu);
                    }


                    Log.e("KYLE_DATA_UPCH",str_name+" "+str_price+""+str_size);
                } 
            }
                catch (JSONException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } 
            else 
            {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
                _errorCode=3;
            }

            return null;
        }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
    {
        ...
    }



}
```

Answer (score 33):

So I actually was able to solve the problem by calling `overridePendingTransition` on the context, casted to an Activity.

```
((Activity) context).overridePendingTransition(R.layout.fade_in, R.layout.fade_out);
```

I realize that this is not the best practice and could get messy with a more complex application, but for our purposes right now I think this is ok. I would like to investigate @bariscan Kayaoglu's solution eventually, as it seems more robust.

Comment: careful, this will crash if the context is not an activity.. Check if the context is an activity first.

Answer (score 9):

Just to add some safety to Tims answer, check if the context is an instance of Activity before casting it:

```
if (context instanceof Activity) {
  ((Activity) context).overridePendingTransition(R.layout.fade_in, R.layout.fade_out);
}
```

This simply makes sure that you call a method that is really there. You could also use a try/catch, but I figure this will be enough

Comment: why we just can't context.overridePendingTransition, because context is of activity? @Bjorn

Answer (score 2):

Better to create an interface and callback its method.

```
myInterface mInterface;
public interface myInterface {
    public abstract void myTask();
}

public GetUPC(myInterface mInterface) {
    this.mInterface = mInterface;
}
```

and in your doInBackground method, when you are done, call

```
mInterface.myTask();
```

Don't forget to implement your interface to your activity and send this to your constructor when you are creating your async task.

```
myAsyncTask = new GetUPC(this);
```

And your development platform will inform you to implement unimplemented methods like myTask(). You can do whatever you want in that method while you can access your activity.

Comment: What exactly would myTask() do here? And does the interface serve as another activity? So would I need to pass the intent to the interface?

Comment: You can call your overridePendingTransition(R.layout.fade_in, R.layout.fade_out); in your myTask() since it is an abstract method, you will fill it in your activity, and your this will be your activity. But as i said earlier, either you cast your context to activity, or use an interface to trigger the time you end your task in async task, the result will be the same, you might trigger your myTask() method or (Activity) context when your Activity is null. As i said earlier, async task is a background thread and it can not know which activity you are on.

Comment: A safer way is to set up a static Activity object and set it every time you open a new intent. Lets say we created a class called Statics, and declared a static Activity, public static Activity activity; and every time you create a new intent, in onCreate you set it like Statics.activity = this; This way you can ensure that your active activity object won't be ever null. But holding static activities most likely cause memory leak if you have memory issues.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that would be a good idea. Since your class is an Async Task, the activity you would choose may not be the active activity since your async task will work in background. But if you consider memory leaks and null pointers, you can just send your activity to your constructor.

Comment: When you say the activity I would choose, do you mean the activity I'll be starting from this async task? Because an activity either of the two activities will be started no matter what, unless an error is returned.  Why exactly would this be a bad idea?

Comment: Well lets say that you started an intent Activity1 to your screen. Started an async task from your Activity1 and send your Activity1 to your async task constructor. Then you start another intent Activity2 while your async task is working behind with the object Activity1. If you would use your Activity1 object in your async task, you would either get null pointer exception depending on the memory or the changes you made would not be seen since your active activity is Activity2. That is the whole point of Async task, it is working asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do any UI updation part from background thread, But if wanted to do the same then override onProgressUpdate of AsyncTask class and past your activity starting code in that. to invoke this methode call publishProgress . Before starting activity you have to cancel your AsyncTask otherwise your application will cress.